# How to query a user account while not logged in Stormpath/Express app?

Tags: express, stormpath

Using Express 4 and **Stormpath**, I want to make public some of the user's account information. Users need not be logged in to view other users' information. They just know the other user's username.

*Example:*
http://localhost:3000/user/jsmith

Will display in the view 'user'

- Username:jsmith
- FirstName: John
- LastName: Smith

I think I can get the view / routes to work, but how do I query the
user accounts in Stormpath by username?

I thought this would be a common task, but couldn't find much.

Thanks,
Rob

**Note:**
This is the tutorial I have working and want to add this feature to:
https://stormpath.com/blog/build-nodejs-express-stormpath-app

---

**This is working, and passes username to view**
In file `server.js`, just above line:

```
app.on('stormpath.ready',function(){ - in example
```

---

```
app.get('/user', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('the response will be sent by the next function ...');
  next();
},
function (req, res) {
req.app.get('stormpathApplication').getAccounts({ username: 'jsmith' }, (err, accounts) => {
  if (err) throw err;
    accounts.each((account, cb) => {
      console.log('Found matching account:', account);
      cb();
      console.log('here comes username')
      console.log(account.username)
  res.send('Hello from user:' + account.username);
    });
  });
}
);
```

Comment: From the stormpath docs: https://docs.stormpath.com/rest/product-guide/latest/accnt_mgmt.html#how-to-search-accounts.

Comment: Thanks, when logged in to Stormpath admin... this works https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/XXXnaFyL1GQDr1YMcYJrV/accounts/?username=jjjsmith and returns a JSON object, but I don't know how to get this into my .js file in Express, and show it in View. I'll keep trying

Comment: In server.js var request = require("request");

request("https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/2XXXXaFyL1GQDr1YMcYJrV/accounts/?username=jjjsmith", function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
}); does not work. I need to pass API keys somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Easy =)

```
app.get('/users/:userName', (req, res, next) => {
  let userName = req.params.userName;
  let account;

  req.app.get('stormpathApplication').getAccounts({ username: userName }, (err, accounts) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    accounts.each((acc, cb) => {
      account = acc;
      console.log('Found matching account:', account);
      cb();
    }, () => {
      return res.json(account);
    ));
  });
```

I'm the original author of this library, that should do it. You can access the underlying Stormpath Application object inside of a route using `req.app.get('stormpathApplication')`.

You can then use the `getAccounts` method of that Application object to search for a user account.

See the API docs for more details: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/jsdoc/Application.html#getAccounts__anchor

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for... but I get an error: `/Users/robmack/sig-test/server.js:27
req.app.get('stormpathApplication').getAccounts({ username: 'jjjsmith' }, (err, accounts) => {
^

ReferenceError: req is not defined'`  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I put code in `server.js` file, see example at: https://stormpath.com/blog/build-nodejs-express-stormpath-app   - also tried it in `profile.js` - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Rob, the example code needs to go inside a route handler.  Can you show us where it is in your application?

Comment: OK, I updated the code sample to show exactly what you need to copy/paste into your`server.js` file to make this work. If you go into that file, go to the very bottom, and find the code that says `app.on('stormpath.ready', ...)` and place this code ABOVE that.

Comment: It's working! with this in server.js, just above stormpath.ready `app.get('/user', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('the response will be sent by the next function ...');
  next();
},
function (req, res) {
req.app.get('stormpathApplication').getAccounts({ username: 'jjjsmith' }, (err, accounts) => {
  if (err) throw err;
    accounts.each((account, cb) => {
      console.log('Found matching account:', account);
      cb();
      console.log('here comes username')
      console.log(account.username)
  res.send('Hello from B!' + account.username);
    });
  });
}
);`

Comment: Great! When you get a moment, would you mind marking this question as answered so anyone else who finds it will know? Thanks! <3